# Is there a way to search the first four characters of a cell in excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, search

Is there a way to tell excel to ONLY search for a text string within the first four characters of a cell?  I was thinking something like:

```
=If(Sumproduct(--isnumber(search({"w1","w2","w3","w4"},left(A2,4))>0
```

The column in A2 contains strings

```
w1 word word word
w2 word word word
w3 word word word
word word w3
word word w1
word word w2
```

My expected output would be

```
w1
w2
w3
blank
blank
blank
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks!

Comment: Needs more context.  Your given sample doesn't match your description.  "word1" is 5 characters, so you'll never get a match looking at the first 4 characters of a cell.  That being said, your provided formula looks like it would work in concept.  Please provide sample data and expected results so that we can better understand and assist.

Comment: give some tables of your excel, input and output please

Comment: I updated my initial description! Let me know if you need any further information. I have the formula nested in an IF statement, but this is the part that seems to be breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this array formula (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>), place in `B2` and drag down:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)={"w1","w2","w3","w4"}))>0,LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1),"")
```

[image]

(To hide the `#VALUE` error, just wrap the above in `IFERROR()`: `=IFERROR([formula above],"")`

Comment: Thank you very much!  This worked fantastic! Would you mind providing an explanation of how it works? Edit: Ah! Nevermind, I figured it out! Brilliant!